# how to add a sales line using OOTB SalesOrder document service

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, aif

I am trying to find an example to add a line to an existing sales order using the OOTB sales order service.

Our client is using the followings steps to do that but getting exception.  I am trying to take a sales order that exists in AX with 1 sales line, and add another sales line to it.

1)  I am using the update method on the SalesOrder service.
2)  I set the entity action to update on the SalesTable
3) I set the entity action to update on the existing sales line
4) I set the entity action to create on the new sales line

What I get is "Invalid Entity action" regarding the new sales line.   If I just update the SalesOrder and sales line without adding a new line it works great. I can't find any examples online about adding a line to an existing sales order. Any pointer or suggestion?

-Fahad

Comment: Could you please specify which AX version and type of adapter you use

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example of how to create a new sales line in an existing sales order here:

[Partial Update With AIF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582243.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped me to write the code quickly to do that.

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2014/10/28/delete-order-line-through-aif